# Is there a clean and easy way to make file path strings in Java OS agnostic?

Tags: java, string, filepath

I've made a class which takes in any string of one format (eg. UNIX) and coverts into whatever OS the java is running on.

```
enum OperatingSystem {
    WINDOWS,
    LINUX;

    static OperatingSystem initOS() {
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");

        switch (osName) {
            case "Windows 8.1":
               return WINDOWS;
            case "Linux":
               return LINUX;
            default:
                return LINUX;
        }
    }

}



public class OSSP {
    public static final OperatingSystem USEROS = OperatingSystem.initOS();


//    Auxilarry methods to return OSAppropriateString
    private static String makeLinuxCompatible(String[] path) {
        return String.join("/", path);
    }

    private static String makeWindowsCompatible(String[] path) {
        return String.join("\\", path);
    }

    public static String getOSSpecificPath(String path) {
        String[] splittedPath = {""}, subpath = {""};
        String finalPath = "";
        if(path.contains("\\")) {
            splittedPath = path.split("\\\\",-1);
        }
        else if (path.contains("/")) {
            splittedPath = path.split("/",-1);
        }

        if (USEROS == OperatingSystem.LINUX) {
            finalPath =  makeLinuxCompatible(splittedPath);
        }
        else if (USEROS == OperatingSystem.WINDOWS) {
            finalPath =  makeWindowsCompatible(splittedPath);
        }
        return finalPath;
    }
}
```

This is fine if you're working on small code and you'd have to do it often.

But, I have a huge GUI code where I'd have to insert this function wherever there is path specified in the program. Is there a way to make path like strings automatically OS specific?

Otherwise a setting where any OS function which takes a path automatically changes accordingly under the hood.

Comment: just use File.separator

Comment: Yep https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator

Comment: FYI, the file system used by default on macOS uses a COLON as the path delimiter rather than a slash. Conveniently, the JVM for Macs automatically translate a Unix-style path with forward-slash SOLIDUS delimiters as if they were COLON characters. I do not know if JVM implementations on other platforms do something similar.

Comment: Cleanest way I can think of would be switching from `java.io.File` to `java.nio.file.Path`. That already has about the same API that you've made, but supported by JDK authors and not you, thus relieving you of burden to test everything yourself.

Comment: @JEY, better yet, instead of all that code above can just be replaced with `Paths.get("/", path)`, I'm pretty sure. He is using Java 8, there's no real reason to continue using `File`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) with [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

```
Path path = Paths.get(".../...");
Path path = Paths.get("...", "...");
// path.resolve, relativize, normalize, getFileSystem
```

This class is a generalisation of `File` which is only for pure file system files.
A path might point in a subdirectory of a .zip using a zip file system and so on.

For established File using APIs one can use `Path.toFile()` and `File.toPath()`.

`Paths.get` is very versatile, also due to the Posix compatibility of Windows (accepting `/` besides `\`). You can get a canonical normalized path anyway.

```
path.toRealPath()
```

The old [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html) you can use:

```
String separator = File.separator;
```

For a path which can point to different [file systems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html):

```
String separator = path.getFileSystem().getSeparator();
```

In general **Path** is a nifty class storing the name parts, the file system.
It covers many aspects like `".."`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with this kind of situation is to not try to detect the OS since that can be rather hit-or-miss. Instead the Java API does provide a way to tell you what character to use as a path separator. Look at this API documentation on File: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html and look for the specific static field `separator`. I would highly suggest you parse the path using the File class then if you need the path as an string simply call `toURI().toString()` to get it into a format that the OS can recognize.